# One post per category set in wordpress theme (tagdiv composer)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

for my website we are using the newspaper theme which works with the tagdiv composer.
Herein you can set how many posts you want to display, and what categories the posts should be pulled from. The options are defined elsewhere in a file, of which below is a snippet of code.

Customisation is limited, however I managed to write a code which takes posts the best scores of the past for weeks, and also to create an alphabetical index based upon taxonomy.

```
        case '28_last_best': 
            $wp_query_args['date_query'] = array(
                        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                        'after' => '4 weeks ago'
            );
            $wp_query_args['meta_key'] = 'score';
            $wp_query_args['meta_value'] = array ( '10', '9.5', '9', '8.5', '8' );            
            $wp_query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $wp_query_args['order'] = 'DESC';
            break;   
        case 'Alphabet_A':                 
            $wp_query_args['tax_query'] = array(
                                                array(
                                                      'taxonomy' => 'alphabetical_letter',
                                                      'field' => 'slug',
                                                      'terms' => array ('A', 'a')
                                                     )
                                               );            
            $wp_query_args['meta_key'] = 'keyword';    
            $wp_query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            $wp_query_args['order'] = 'ASC';
            break;
```

Each seperate case can be selected in the composer.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to create a new case, to display 4 posts (number of which is set in tagdiv composer) from all categories (also set in tagdiv composer) but I would like to see just one post for each category. Any thoughts on how I might achieve this, given the above example ?

Earlier code I tried was this but that clearly didnt work out... it just shows all the most recent posts, ignoring the per page setting. What am I missing here ?

```
$wp_query_args['tax_query'] = array(
                    'cat' => $category->term_id,
                    'orderby' =>'post_date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1');
```